# How to write without keyboard?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, input

my uncle can't type with keyboard quickly in our local language but they can write on paper using pen very quick. Is there any other easy hardware to write e-mail, letter, chatting in windows XP.

like we write freely on paper.

Answer (score 3):

Handwriting recognition is actually built-in by default in Windows XP. Look here for how to install it:

> [How to install and configure handwriting recognition in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306906)

Of course you'll still need a "writing tool" to make use of it. From the requirements:

> - A writing tool. The minimum
>     requirement for a writing tool is a
>     mouse. To write with your mouse, press
>     and hold down the primary mouse
>     button, and then move the mouse
>     pointer to form characters. The
>     recommended tool is a handwriting
>     input device, such as a pen stylus and
>     tablet, connected to your computer
>     through a serial port or USB port.
>     Graphics tablets that are used with
>     three-dimensional (3-D) drawing or
>     computer-aided design (CAD) programs
>     can also be used.

Comment: can u advice for a low cost but good hardware in A4 size to just write mail and letters in word i don't need 3D and CAD program facility. you are write i need like pen or paper.

Comment: @Jitendra: I have no hands-on experience for this kind of devices. I would recommend you to search for "a4 handwriting tablet" (http://www.google.com/products?q=a4+handwriting+tablet&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=ZeODS6_qHIOy0gSG3uDKAg&sa=X&oi=product_result_group&ct=title&resnum=3&ved=0CCEQrQQwAg) in whatever shop you normally buy your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Wacom's [Bamboo](http://www.wacom.com/bamboo/bamboo_pen.php) line.  The one I've linked there (Bamboo Pen) is probably the best for your uncle, though it's not quite as big as an 8.5" x 11" sheet of paper.  This device's dimensions are just 9.8" x 6.9", though that should be good enough.  If you are interested in paying another $130 for a slightly better product that is also bigger (8.8" x 13.3"), check out the [Bamboo Fun](http://www.wacom.com/bamboo/bamboo_fun.php).

The first one is only $70.  That's pretty reasonable.

If you have a scanner (used for photos, documents, etc.) you could hand-write something (if your writing is clear enough) and use OCR technology to translate that into text.  You can definitely find free OCR software very easily, and that's only if it didn't come with the scanner (which, it usually does).  This is still assuming you have a scanner.

Without a scanner, your best option would probably be coughing up the $70 and buying the Bamboo Pen.